# QueryDsl MongoDB - Accessing Deeply Nested Object for Query

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I have issues trying to access nested object when using `BooleanBuilder`. I have read that the default is 2 levels, but for my use case, I need to access 3rd level nested objects. So I have added `@QueryInit` as pointed out in many other answers. But I still cannot access it. Here is my code:

```
@Document
public class Order implements Serializable {

     @QueryInit(*.*)
     private Item item;

}

public class Item implements Serializable {
   private Details details;
}

public class Details implements Serializable {
   private String name;
}

public static BooleanExpression name(String name) {
  QOrder order = QOrder.order;
  return order.item.details.name.eq(name)
}
```

I have `QOrder`, `QItem` classes generated and working fine. But details.description gives error because `QDetails` class was not generated. How do I make it generate `QDetails`?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is that you missed a semicolon on the return statement which might be causing you some other issues. The way to generate `QDetails` is to first reference the query, and request the details from the assigned result.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by referencing the query?